# ReactJS setState when all nested Axios calls are finished

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, axios, es6-promise

I have a problem with updating my state from nested axios call inside forEach loop:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoaded: false,
      items: []
    };
    //Binding fetch function to component's this
    this.fetchFiles = this.fetchFiles.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchFiles();
  }

  fetchFiles() {
    axios.get('/list')
    .then((response) => {
      var items = response.data.entries;
      items.forEach((item, index) => {
        axios.get('/download'+ item.path_lower)
        .then((response) => {
          item.link = response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        })
      });
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        isLoaded: true,
        items: items
      }));
      console.log(this.state.items);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
```

The idea is to get all items from Dropbox using it's API (JavaScript SDK)
and then for each item I also need to call different API endpoint to get a temporary download link and assign it as a new property. Only after all items will get their links attached I want to setState and render the component. Could somebody please help with this, I spend already multiple hours fighting with promises :S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `Promise.all` to wait for multiple promises. Also keep in mind that `setState` is async and you wont see immediate changes. You need to pass a callback.

```
  fetchFiles() {
    axios.get('/list')
    .then((response) => {
      var items = response.data.entries;

      // wait for all nested calls to finish
      return Promise.all(items.map((item, index) => {
        return axios.get('/download'+ item.path_lower)
          .then((response) => {
            item.link = response.data;
            return item
          });
      }));     
    })
    .then(items => this.setState(prevState => ({
        isLoaded: true,
        items: items
      }), () => console.log(this.state.items)))
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
```

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!!! I was trying to make use of Promise.All but I got confused with it. Your solution works as I wanted!!

Comment: @JavaEvgen Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try making the fetchfiles() function as an asynchronous method by adding the **async** keyword.Now, we have to wait till the items to get their download link, so add a **await** keyword before that line which makes the code to wait till the axios call gets completed.

```
async function fetchFiles() {
axios.get('/list')
.then(async function(response){
  var items = response.data.entries;
  await items.forEach((item, index) => {
    axios.get('/download'+ item.path_lower)
    .then((response) => {
      item.link = response.data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  });
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    isLoaded: true,
    items: items
  }));
  console.log(this.state.items);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
})
}
```

I haven't tested the code, but it should probably work.

Comment: Can you please explain why?

Comment: Simply because `await` awaits for promises. `Array.prototype.forEach` returns undefined.

Comment: Thanks for it. I thought it'll work for all the statements.

Comment: It works with any expression in a sense. Here it will be equivalent to  `Promise.resolve(undefined).then(/* rest of your code*/)` which "kinda works" but not as expected :)