# Nested axios call within a loop does not render data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My component makes three different axios call where two of the axios calls gets called within another inside a loop which is shown below. When the component is finished rendering it only renders the data from the first axois call `getAllSearchResults` but the other two axios call `getProductsByIds` and `getLegalNamesById` does not render the data when the component first renders unless I interact with the component like clicking on the component then it renders. I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

```
let panels = {documentSource: {summary: 'Document Source', content: new Set()},
  legalName: {summary: 'Legal Name', content: new Set()},
  productName: {summary: 'Product Name', content: new Set()},};

const RenderData = () => {

  const [accordionResults, setAccordionResults] = useState(null);
  const [isLoadingLegalName, setIsLoadingLegalName] = useState(true);
  const [isLoadingProductName, setIsLoadingProductName] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
      fetchResults();
  }, []);
  
  const fetchResults = () => {
    return searchService()
    .getAllSearchResults("search", 650)
    .then((response) => {
      let results = response.data.results;
      if (results.length > 0) {
        Promise.all(results.map((obj, index) => {
          panels.documentSource.content.add(obj.A.value[0]);
          getLegalName(obj.B.value[0]);
          getProductName(obj.C.value[0]);
        }))
      }
      setAccordionResults(panels);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  };

  const getLegalName = (id) => {
    return CommonRefService()
    .getLegalNamesById([id])
    .then((response) => {
      const legalName = response.data.results[0];
      panels.legalName.content.add(legalName.name + ' - ' + legalName.id);
      setIsLoadingLegalName(false);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  };

  const getProductName = (id) => {
    return commonService()
    .getProductsByIds([id])
    .then((response) => {
      const productName = response.data[0].prodType;
      panels.productName.content.add(productName);
      setIsLoadingProductName(false);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  };
  
  if(isLoadingProductName || isLoadingLegalName) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
```

I tried the above approach

Comment: `if (results.length > 0)` then `setAccordionResults(panels);` will never run - because you `return Promise.all(results.map((obj, index) => {` ... though, not sure why you do that, since `results.map` won't result in any Promises at all

Comment: @JaromandaX That was a typo, I have updated the code

Comment: so, now `setAccordionResults(panels);` will run before anything in `Promise.all(results.map((obj, index) => {` - why are you even using `Promise.all` since the `.map` doesn't return any Promises, nor do you do anything with the result of Promise.all?

Comment: @JaromandaX I was using this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50448013/reactjs-setstate-when-all-nested-axios-calls-are-finished. That is why I came here for help. Not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: you're not using Promises correctly

Comment: @JaromandaX I refactored my code to not even use `Promise.all` or `then` where I only used `await` and I still have the same issue.

Comment: perhaps something like [this](https://pastebin.com/3j7AQpgs) - though, I'd use async/await, personally - something like [this](https://pastebin.com/zUNGiQJG)

Comment: the only other potential issue is that you call `setIsLoadingLegalName(false);` and `setIsLoadingProductName(false);` for each iteration of `results.map((obj, index) => {`

Comment: another potential issue is that `panels.???.content.add` won't all be added in the same order - is that a problem?

Comment: @JaromandaX Panels not being added in same order shouldn't be a problem.